# sql - order by column (the column has all null values)

Tags: sql

```
Select M1.alias, F1.D11 As debitAmt
from Master1 M1 inner join Folio1 F1 on F1.MasterCode = M1.Code
order by M1.alias
```

I have the following resultset:

Alias   |   DebitAmt

```
    |   70009

    |   5500

    |   1100000

    |   0

    |   81400
```

How is order by alias performed above when there are no values in it ?

Comment: Null values are either sorted first or last in the result.

Comment: You answered yourself!

Comment: If you want to control the sorting, use e.g. `order by m1.alias nulls last` or `nulls first`

Answer (score 1):

> How is order by alias performed above when there are no values in it ?

The same way that any other values with ties are sorted.  They are not.

SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no "default" ordering to fall back on when there are ties in the keys, so the sorting is arbitrary.  It is not only arbitrary, but it might change from one run to the next.

If you want a more canonical sort, add additional sort keys so the sort keys uniquely identify each row.  Then the sort is *stable*, meaning that the same results are returned each time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use your concatenated operation column `D11` with you to manage your null column to be also sorted;

```
Select M1.alias, F1.D11 As debitAmt
from Master1 M1 inner join Folio1 F1 on F1.MasterCode = M1.Code
order by M1.alias, F1.D11
```

Answer (score 0):

> How is order by alias performed above when there are no values in it ?

How the sorting is done depends on the DBMS:

- A DBMS may see from statistical table data that all values are null and simply ignore the `ORDER BY` clause. (The same thing applies for the case that all rows contain a value in the column, but it's the same value for all rows.)
- If the DBMS does not see it or does not care, it will sort the rows. But as all the values are null there is no row that must come before another. No sorting is needed. Depending on the internal sort algorithm the already arbitrary row order may remain untouched or may get shuffled.

As to the result: No matter how the `ORDER BY` clause is handled internally, you get an indeterministic order. The same is true for a query without any `ORDER BY` clause, by the way.